# How can I write Mathematica code for this continued fraction with alternating terms?

Tags: continued-fractions

$$\varphi+\cfrac{1}{\varphi^{-1}+\cfrac{1}{\varphi+\cfrac{1}{\varphi^{-1}+\cfrac{1}{\varphi+\cdots}}}}$$

I saw this continued fraction on Facebook. I need the Mathematica code for this using continued fraction or `Nest` or `Fold`. Normal continued fraction code is not working for me, as I am new to Mathematica. Looking for help in this, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `ContinuedFractionK[]` for this:

```
φ + ContinuedFractionK[1, φ^(1 - 2 Boole[Mod[k, 2] == 1]), {k, n}]
```

---

Greg Martin suggests the simpler expression

```
φ + ContinuedFractionK[1, φ^((-1)^k), {k, n}]
```

---

An exercise for the motivated reader is to prove that this is equivalent to the simpler

```
(Fibonacci[n + 2] φ)/Fibonacci[n + 1]
```

Comment: `φ^(1 - 2 Boole[Mod[k, 2] == 1])` is unnecessarily complicated; `φ^(1 - 2 Mod[k, 2])` works just as well, as does `φ^((-1)^k)`.

Comment: Indeed, thank you @Greg. I thought about `φ^((-1)^k)` only quite a while after writing this answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
z = Defer /@ {-1, ""};
φ + Nest[1/(φ^Last[z = RotateLeft[z]] + #) &, …, 5]
```

[image]

```
z = Defer /@ {Style[-1, 14], ""};
Style[φ + Nest[1/(φ^Last[z = RotateLeft@z] + #) &, …, 5], 32, ScriptSizeMultipliers -> 1]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
z = φ^(Defer /@ {Style[-1, 14], ""});
i = 1;
Style[φ + Nest[1/(z[[Mod[i++, 2, 1]]] + #) &, …, 5], 32, ScriptSizeMultipliers -> 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Fold[]` for this (an example from Documentation Center):

```
ϕ + Fold[1/(#2 + #1) &, ϕ, Reverse[Table[ϕ^(1 - 2 Boole[Mod[k, 2] == 1]), {k, 1, 7}]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) to find the value of this continued fraction by noticing that it satisfies a recursion relation:

$$
x = \varphi + \frac{1}{\varphi^{-1}+\frac{1}{x}}
$$

```
Solve[x == φ + 1/(φ^-1 + 1/x), x] // FullSimplify

(*    {{x -> -1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5]) φ},
       {x -> 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]) φ}}        *)

% /. φ -> GoldenRatio // FullSimplify

(*    {{x -> -1},
       {x -> 1/2 (3 + Sqrt[5])}}    *)
```

The first of these solutions is an unstable fixed point and the second is a stable fixed point. So in reality only the second of these solutions represents the limit of an infinite continued fraction.

Stability analysis: by setting

$$
x_{n+1} = \varphi + \frac{1}{\varphi^{-1}+\frac{1}{x_n}}
$$

we see that

$$
\frac{dx_{n+1}}{dx_n} = \frac{\varphi^2}{(\varphi+x_n)^2}
$$

which for the first solution gives

```
D[φ + 1/(φ^-1 + 1/x), x] /. x -> -1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5]) φ // FullSimplify

(*    1/2 (7 + 3 Sqrt[5])    *)
```

(magnitude is larger than 1, so unstable) and for the second solution gives

```
D[φ + 1/(φ^-1 + 1/x), x] /. x -> 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]) φ // FullSimplify

(*    4/(3 + Sqrt[5])^2    *)
```

(magnitude is smaller than 1, so stable).

Comment: The result of `GoldenRatio^2` is consistent with the closed form in my answer, if `φ` is taken as `GoldenRatio`, and $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else has put it out here and I'm not 100% clear from The Question that `FromContinuedFraction` is disallowed or just not working as the OP expects.

```
FromContinuedFraction[{{GoldenRatio, GoldenRatio^-1}}]
```