# How can we generate this more general form of the continued fraction?

Tags: continued-fractions

[How can I write Mathematica code for this continued fraction with alternating terms?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221965/how-can-i-write-mathematica-code-for-this-image-continued-fraction-with-altern)

How can we generate this more general form of the above-continued fraction?

$$x+\cfrac{a}{y+\cfrac{a^2}{x+\cfrac{a^3}{y+\cfrac{a^4}{x+\cfrac{a^5}{y+\cfrac{a^6}{x+\cdots}}}}}}$$

Comment: Yes thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Once again, you can use `ContinuedFractionK[]`:

```
With[{n = 7}, 
     x + ContinuedFractionK[a^k, Piecewise[{{y, Mod[k, 2] == 1}}, x], {k, 1, n}]]
```

$$x+\cfrac{a}{y+\cfrac{a^2}{x+\cfrac{a^3}{y+\cfrac{a^4}{x+\cfrac{a^5}{y+\cfrac{a^6}{x+\cfrac{a^7}{y}}}}}}}$$

Answer (score 4):

```
z = {x, y};
i = 1;
n = 6;
Style[x + Nest[a^(n - i++)/(z[[Mod[i, 2, 1]]] + #) &, …, n - 1], 32,
  ScriptSizeMultipliers -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.